# Not getting access token response in postman

Tags: api, postman, http-status-code-404, response, access-token

I am using below mentioned **API** and **keys** to get **access token** from **Postman** :-

POST  [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e

scope=User.Read%20CallRecords.Read.All%20Mail.Read%20mail.read

code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...

redirect_uri=https://office365test.com

grant_type=authorization_code

client_secret=xxx

It is **not showing access token and refresh token attributes** and the **status** is **404 Not Found**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, 404 means not found, it did not find the resource. That `{tenant}` in the URL should be a real tenant name, do you set it before sending the request?

Comment: Hi Pavelsaman, yes I have set it before sending the request.